# Gnuplot, simple xy graph, bug?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file called plot.txt with a number of values such as:

1   7.5000000000000000
           2   10.312500000000000
           3   11.660156250000000
           4   12.425537109375000
           5   12.913055419921875
           6   13.248996734619141
           7   13.493841290473938
           8   13.679883163422346
           9   13.825851876754314
          10   13.943356417876203

This list continuous until about 450. When i try to plot it with lines i get a linear line across the graph. Why is this? [line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDIm2.png) And how do I get rid of it?

```
open(newunit=write_unit,access='sequential',file='plotgnu.txt',status='unknown')


write(write_unit,*)'plot ''plot.txt'' with linespoints '


close(write_unit,status='keep')

!Kaller på gnuplot
call execute_command_line("gnuplot -persist plotgnu.txt")
```

When i plot it without linespoints I get the the correct graph just with points [point graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Eip.png)

```
write(write_unit,*)'plot ''plot.txt'' '
```

Comment: Hard to say without having the full data file. Could be that the last line in your data file repeats the first line, which is visible only when you connect the points with a line

Comment: Ok, here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9CEsYCSSZUSUU9WZlI3SjBUbm8/view?usp=sharing  need more rep points to add it in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data file contains the same data set four times without empty lines:

```
1   7.5000000000000000     
2   10.312500000000000     
...
437   14.999999999999998     
438   14.999999999999998     
1   7.5000000000000000     
2   10.312500000000000     
...
```

If you plot that `with lines` you do of course also get a line from the last point of the first "data set" to the first point of the second occurrence of the data set. And that is the line you are seeing.